# Making a scrollable responsive gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

For a university project, I am working on a UWP application that shows current weather information and has a Cortana like interface to controll certain parts of a smart home.

The interface exists out of three columns with one row for the desktop view and these three columns are aligned as three rows in one column on mobile devices. This part I figured out by following a tutorial and alteringthe code to fit my specific needs.

I now have the problem that the columns, when put as a row are scaled down to fit 1/3rd of the screen. I set a hardcoded size of 500 to see if I could work with fixed values since the inner elements don't change size much. However when i do this the view is not scrollable and most part of the second row and the entire third row is not visible for the user.
I have tried solving this by adding code below to the main grid but with no result.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

**TL;DR: How do I make my responsive grid layout so that it is scrollable when the grid gets too big.**

XAML code:

```
<Page
x:Class="UWPWeather.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UWPWeather"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/blue-sea-horizon.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1100" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="0*"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height" Value="0*"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="1*"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width" Value="1*"/>
                    <Setter Target="FirstGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="FirstGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 0 6"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.Margin" Value="0 6 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height" Value="500"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="500"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[2].Height" Value="500"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="0*"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width" Value="0*"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Target="ThirdGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="ThirdGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Grid x:Name="FirstGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent">
            <Button x:Name="StartRecognition" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200" Click="StartVoiceRecog">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Assets/microphone.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="SecondGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,50,0,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="LocationTextBlock" FontSize="36" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                    <Image x:Name="ResultImage" Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="TempTextBlock" FontSize="60" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock x:Name="DescriptionTextBlock" Padding="5" FontSize="36" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="5">
                    <Image x:Name="WindDirection" Width="20" Height="20" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="WindSpeed" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock x:Name="Pressure" Padding="5" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Humidity" Padding="5" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image x:Name="SunRiseImage" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Sunrise" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"  />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image x:Name="SunsetImage" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Sunset" FontSize="12" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Button x:Name="UpdateWeather" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="49" Width="39" Click="UpdateWeatherOnClick">
                    <Button.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/012_restart-512.png"/>
                    </Button.Background>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="ThirdGrid" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Interface concept:

[Interface wide](https://snag.gy/3WmaZ6.jpg)

[Interface narrow](https://snag.gy/FiuIgd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI elements won't become scrollable just because you set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"` attached property on them. These attached properties are only useful on elements which contain a ScrollViewer in their template (it is *that* ScrollViewer which will take on the values of the attached properties).

If you want your `MainGrid` to be scrollable, you need to wrap it in a ScrollViewer. You will also need to hoist the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` attached property from `MainGrid` into the ScrollViewer. `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` must be attached to the template root otherwise it will have no effect.

```
<Page>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            ...
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Comment: I tried that, If I wrap the grid in a scrollviewer it loses the responsiveness created with the VisuelStateManager is there a way to wrap it in the scrollviewer and still keep the responsiveness?

Comment: When you wrap your `MainGrid` in a ScrollViewer, make sure to lift the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` from inside the `MainGrid` up into the ScrollViewer. VisualStateGroups must be set on the template root element otherwise it will have no effect.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake I hadn't tried that yet. I was under the impression VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups was part of the grid element.